# Where can I find ETFs that go up when the market goes down?

Tags: etf, trading

If the general market index goes down, is there a concept of an ETF that will go up on those scenarios?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  What you're asking about are called **[inverse ETFs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_exchange-traded_fund)**.  Sometimes these inverse ETFs are also *leveraged* to provide 2x, 3x, etc. of the downside.  But, beware:

> An inverse ETF as any leveraged ETF needs to buy when the market rises
>   and sell when it falls in order to maintain a fixed leverage ratio.
>   **This results in a volatility loss proportional to the market
>   variance.** Compared to a short position with identical initial
>   exposure, the inverse ETF will therefore usually deliver inferior
>   returns. [...] *(Source: Wikipedia. Emphasis mine.)*

Inverse ETFs aren't hard to find – they trade on the same stock exchanges regular ETFs trade on. You should have access through your broker if you can already buy ETFs.  If you're interested in a list of specific inverse ETFs, [here's one](http://www.tradermike.net/inverse-short-etfs-bearish-etf-funds/).  Be careful with these.

Some related Q&A here:

- [Trying to understand the toxicity of a Leveraged ETF as a hedge](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12293/trying-to-understand-the-toxicity-of-a-leveraged-etf-as-a-hedge)
- [What kinds of exchange-traded funds (ETFs) should specifically be avoided?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/564/what-kinds-of-exchange-traded-funds-etfs-should-specifically-be-avoided)
- [How do you short US Treasuries?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/how-do-you-short-us-treasuries)
- [“Diversifying” by going Long and Short Simultaneously](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/diversifying-by-going-long-and-short-simultaneously)

Comment: To be explicit, leveraged ETFs track intra-day market performance; however, since US Equity Futures markets are open nearly 24 hours on business days (and Sunday afternoon), the OP will be very disappointed in performance if he does anything other than day-trade a leveraged ETF.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to look for ETF names with words like ***short*** or ***bear / bearish*** those are the ones that go up when the market goes down.

Their counterparts are the ones that gain twice the market when it increases, but they also loss twice when it decreases. In these ETFs you usually find the word ***leverage / leveraged***, because they basically borrow money (leverage) to invest more in the market.