# Is investing in 2x QQQ (QLD) the same as investing in my account buying QQQ but making it 2x using my margin?

Tags: margin, nasdaq, leveraged-etf

It seems to matter for the following, if the increase or decrease happens evenly over 30 days vs if it happen overnight, for the case of Account 1, but does not matter for Account 2. So what if (1) it is a little bit evenly over 30 days, and (2) if it happens overnight, such as from Jan 31 to Feb 1, it increases 100% overnight, and the drop from Feb 28 to March 1, also overnight?

#### January 1st

Let's say, if I have $100, and invest in

```
Account 1: QLD, which is 2x QQQ
Account 2: QQQ but I borrow the max and can buy $200 worth of QQQ
```

#### February 1st

Now it is Feb 1, and QQQ rises from $100 to $200.  So how much money are in my Account 1 and 2 on Feb 1?

#### March 1st

And now it is March 1, and QQQ drops from $200 to $100.

How much money are in my Account 1 and 2 on March 1?

Account 1 could have $0 now because it dropped 50% and the 2x effect makes it go to $0.
Account 2 could have $100 now because QQQ just went up and back down to where it was at first. It is as if nothing has happened (except a little bit margin interest I have to pay), and I am back to where I was: $100.

Is that how it is?  Account 1 has $0, or does it have $100 like Account 2, or what does it have?

(I think this may have something to do with "[rebalancing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/69879/why-are-daily-rebalanced-inverse-leveraged-etfs-bad-for-long-term-investing)", as the leverage ETF seems to have "daily effect"... but how does it happen? The fund manager doesn't just speak "rebalancing" and it can magically happen. He has to do something. What does he do and what is really happening?  And **the real question is, on March 1, how much money is in my Account 1 and Account 2?**)

Comment: If the QQQ drops 50%, both accounts are wiped out.

Comment: @BobBaerker Not true for Account 1 if QQQ drops a cumulative 50% over more than one day. Not true for Account 2 if QQQ drops 50% *after* having already gone up, because Account 2 does not rebalance (after a rise the leverage is less than 2x).

Comment: OK, that wasn't well phrased on my part.  If he's on full margin in the QQQ account (100% borrowed), if the QQQ drops immediately, his equity is wiped out.  Account value dropping 50% is another story and yes, I'm not addressing the multitude of scenarios posed.

Comment: I think it's important to note that QQQ increasing steadily over the course of 30 days is extremely unlikely to happen, and that the actual performance of QLD will be worse than what the performance would be if QQQ did increase steadily.

Answer (score 1):

The question cannot be answered for Account 1, because it depends on the sequence of daily returns of QQQ. The monthly return of QLD cannot be inferred from the monthly return of QQQ. QLD would not go to zero unless QQQ dropped 50% in a single day.

You can explore scenarios for QLD yourself by compounding 2x daily returns. To address the two special (unrealistic) cases you asked about:

- If QQQ returns are very smooth (same *small* percentage move each day), then QLD will approximately vary with the *square* of QQQ. (This is because returns are geometric and the exponent is being doubled.) So, with QQQ rising smoothly in January, your QLD is worth ~$400 on February 1, and with QQQ falling smoothly in February, your QLD is worth ~$100 on March 1. The exact numbers will be different (worse), because doubling or halving in a month is not that small a daily return, and time decay will come into play.
- If QQQ is flat except for making its entire move on one day each month, then the 100% rise causes a 200% rise in QLD, and the 50% fall causes a 100% fall in QLD. So your QLD is worth $300 on February 1 and $0 on March 1.

For Account 2, ignoring interest and trading costs, the value is $300 on February 1 and $100 on March 1.

Comment: i added to the question: what if (1) it is a little bit evenly over 30 days, and (2) if it happens overnight, such as from Jan 31 to Feb 1, it increases 100% overnight, and the drop from Feb 28 to March 1, also overnight?

Comment: if QQQ smoothly goes up over the 30 days, can't we use some spreadsheet to actually calculate day by day how it does, and then for the other 28 days of slowing coming down as well... I guess we just have to put in the mechanism of: it has to be 2x effect per day

Comment: @nonopolarity Yes, a spreadsheet would give the most accurate estimate (what I referred to as "compounding 2x daily returns").

Answer (score 0):

**Account 1** would have $100 minus the [decay](https://www.kiplinger.com/article/investing/t022-c009-s001-run-don-t-walk-from-leveraged-etfs.html) that is inherent to holding an inverse ETF or leveraged ETF. Let's assume that the decay is $28 after two months. $100 minus $28 = **$72**

**Account 2**, assuming that there was no margin call while the stock dropped 50%, would have the full $200 that you started with, the $100 debt and some interest charged. $200 - $100 - $1 = **$99**

Comment: You pay interest on margin borrowing.

Comment: Thanks, edited it.