# Is using debt into a regular mutual fund different from investing in a leveraged mutual fund?

Tags: investing, debt, rebalancing, leverage

I was thinking if I should invest in some mutual funds using low-interest rate debt. But then I read this Q&A: [Why are daily rebalanced inverse/leveraged ETFs bad for long term investing?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/69879/why-are-daily-rebalanced-inverse-leveraged-etfs-bad-for-long-term-investing)

- If I use my loan on regular mutual funds, can I avoid the daily rebalancing effect from leveraged mutual funds?

  - If so, is it also good for long-term investment, unlike leveraged mutual funds?
- Are there any other differences between leveraged mutual funds and loan-fueled regular mutual funds?
- I think I don't quite understand the "daily rebalancing". What's different between with and without daily rebalancing?

Comment: Gambling is bad enough, but gambling with borrowed money is a really high risk prospect.  What are you going to do if the value of the fund you've invested in goes down?

Comment: @SimonB You are right. I'll not do that. But my curiosity still remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one important difference: If you invest in a leveraged fund, you can only lose 100% of your investment. If you take on debt to invest, you can lose more.

For simplicity let us assume that you are having double leverage and your investment drops by 60%. With a leveraged fund you will be wiped out at 50% and that's it. If you borrowed money, you are now in debt. If you are speculating using a margin account you will receive a margin call well before the 50% but if you are using uncorrelated debt (like consumer debt, HELOC) this can be a real problem. An investment may take a very long time to recover or maybe it never will.